# iOS app crashing because of FlurryAds

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, flurry

I am experiencing a hard to debug problem. My program crashes because a message is sent to a deallocated object. Using Zombie Objects, I have found out what is causing it to crash, but don't know how to fix it. When my view dissappears, I set the FlurryAds delegate to nil, and upon that view appearing I set it to the view. When I background my app and am in this view, I immediately get a crash. Is there a bug in Flurry?

This is the message printed to the console:

```
2013-01-18 14:04:44.626 Purdue Course Sniper[19212:c07] *** -[FlurryAd space]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa6ac490
```

I am not sending this message anywhere ^^. Why is this message being sent anyways? The delegate is set to nil..

[image: Flurry Image]

Comment: Looks like in the method "-[FlurryAd removeTakeoverWindows]" has one call and make the reference count -1. You might want to check that function. Or maybe you can provide the code so we can take a look?

Comment: I am not directly calling that function anywhere. These are all called by the Flurry API..

Comment: I get the error as soon as I background my app.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Flurry and I will be happy to help. I need to understand a little more about your integration. Namely, more about this statement "When my view dissappears, I set the FlurryAds delegate to nil, and upon that view appearing I set it to the view". What view is disappearing and appearing? Is this a fullscreen ad? It would also help to know details of your account with Flurry. Can you send an email to support@flurry.com so we can access your account? Thanks and sorry you are experiencing an issue.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: Hi, I just emailed Flurry. What I mean is, when the view displays ads shows up, I set the delegate to that view. When it disappears, I set the delegate to nil. Whenever I background my application, this is the error that I receive. I am on iOS5.0 and this is occurring in the simulator and on the device. 

Edit: This is a full screen ad that is being displayed. Even when the ad is not displayed though(because it is only displayed every third time the search button is clicked), I still receive an error when I background the app.